# Has anyone satisfied the UK fiancee/spouse visa financial requirements by working their foreign job remotely as someone self-employed in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom

I'm a UK citizen with a Japanese fiancee. We plan to get married in the UK, so we want to apply for his entry under the fiancee visa. However, we don't meet the financial requirements yet -- I'm searching for, but haven't yet secured, a UK-based job. That said, I have a Japanese job that meets the income requirement and would be willing for me to work remotely.

I spoke to a Japanese visa firm who suggested it would be possible to count J-income if

1. I paid tax on the income in the UK.
2. I became self-employed in the UK and submitted that documentation.

However, it seems like the forms for the self-employed look to a past year of s.e. income, which I don't have.

Tldr; Has anyone satisfied the UK fiancee/spouse visa financial requirements by working their foreign job remotely as someone self-employed in the UK?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is "no" on the basis of :

9. Self-employment or Director or employee of a specified limited company in the UK
   9.1. Category F: Last full financial year
   9.1.1. Where the applicant’s partner (and/or the applicant if they are in the UK with permission to work) is in self-employment, or is either the director or employee (or both) of a specified limited company in the UK, at the date of application, they can use income from the **last full financial yea** to meet the financial requirement.

Comment: In the last line, do you mean "...last full financial **year**...?